# Is it possible to intercept the username and password when user submit the login form?

Tags: authentication, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

In Lotus Domino, when user submits the login form, we need to intercept user's `username` and `password` and `relogin` him/her to `Domino` with **another** `username` and `password`, according to his/her input `username` and `password`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have a look at the domcfg.nsf, you can provide custom login forms.

Comment: It sounds weird. Anyway, did you try to set first login as alias for the user (so user can use any of them to log in)? Or do you transform password too (what is pretty bad idea from security standpoint)?

Comment: I agree that it sounds weird. It may be a case where DSAPI has to come into play, but it's difficult to tell from what's actually stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a custom login and Access it with a URL: /names.nsf?login&Redirectto=/myDb.nsf/loginredirect?OpenForm

In the loginredirect user would be logged in with the username he enters. You will have to RELOG in with the **another** user. see http://dominounlimited.blogspot.co.il/2008/07/automated-login-to-domino-by-http-post.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in domino but it requires you to write a DSAPI filter, which can be complicated. DSAPI filter allowes you to validate the password and go around dominos password validation.

A easier solutions is to have another authentication server which logs in the user to domino, this will involve letting the authentication server doing a POST of the login form to domino  and then give the session cookie to the user.